# What's the difference between the tags of git push and git commit

Tags: git, github, command, commit

I started to use git about 1 month, but i'm kind of the user that do the commands because knows that works, but don't know exacly why. So i've made some research on the internet looking for some answers, but some of them i can't find.

So far, my bests references are:
[try.github.io](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/25), [git - the simple gide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/), some posts here in StackOverflow and the help gide of Github.

So, what's the differences between the targets that we use when we are about to commit? For example, just now i've made a push on my GitHub, and i tried to use `git commit -a` instead `git commit -m "comments"` and it didn't work. I've seen that exists `git commit -am` too. Is it the same thing that the last two? On the same way, mostly when i search on internet, i see people using `git push origin master` when i always use just `git push`. Such varieties confuse me sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing to all the commands that you mentioned in the question..

- `git commit -a` will open up a editor for you to enter the commit message and the `-a` argument adds all the files that have been tracked by git but are modified in this commit.
- `git commit -m "This is the commit message"` allows you to write the commit message in the command itself, so you don''t have to type it in a editor. For this to work, you should already `git add file1 file2 ..` files whose changes you want to commit.
- `git commit -am` is just a fancy way of writing `git commit -a -m`, and as you should've learnt from above points.. `-a` argument/option will add the files and `-m` option allows you to give a inline commit message.
- `git push origin master` - in this `origin` is the remote and `master` is the branch to be pushed... Using `git push` works for you because you had set the upstream branch earlier with this command `git push -u origin master`, hence, you won't have to tell git every time you push. Using `-u` tells git to remember the `remote` and `branch` for the current checked out branch.

Also, if you need more help, you can use `man`pages or `git --help`, you should even consider reading [*Pro Git*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) for further deeper understanding

---

Answer (score 0):

It's all about getting familiar with Git and how it works. Once you get more comfortable, you'll start using shortcuts that do the same thing and save you time.
So lets say you created a branch and edited some files. Now you want to push these changes and see them on your remote branch. You would go something like this:

```
git status
git add .
git commit -m "First commit for branch"
git push
```

An easier way would be to just combine the add command with the commit command. You can do so as follows:

```
git commit -a -m "First commit for branch"
```

As far as using `git push` is concerned, it will push your current branch to the remote branch with the same name.
A `git push origin master` will push your master branch to the origin.

If you are going to use `git push`, then you need to make sure you are pushing the correct branch. You can check the branch you are currently on by using `git branch`.